# Sum all counter by one lablel - prometheus

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, metrics, promql

Hi everybody I have an error counter that gives me metrics like below, I want to get a total sum of each error reason in the last 7 days. I've tried using increase but it seems that the increase function doesn't support `by/without` operators so I get results including `machine_type`.

How can I not include `machine_type` in the query result?

```
{instance="localhost:8000", job="prometheus", reason="Some_reason", machine_type="gpu"}
```

This is what I've tried
`increase(error_count_total[24h])`
And results are

```
{instance="localhost:8000", job="prometheus", reason="Some_reason", machine_type="gpu"}: 15
{instance="localhost:8000", job="prometheus", reason="Some_reason", machine_type="cpu"}: 10
```

And I want to get

```
{instance="localhost:8000", job="prometheus", reason="Some_reason"}: 25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
sum without (machine_type) (increase(error_count_total[24h]))
```